# React native application crash on Multiple state variable along with view has changed in a screen with out any error message

Tags: react-native, performance, react-hooks, react-redux

In my React-Native application, There is a screen where multiple state(using useState variable) change occurs simultaneously and according to it conditional rendering view has changed and as this goes on repeatedly after some time there will UI get stuck and not responding and then the application get crashed without any error message,Please i have no idea about that crash, i think due to multiple state change and view changing causes multiple rendering and UI thread get blocked or may be due to state variable use memory consumption occured which caused app crash...not understanding..Please help me to identify the errors and what is the solutions to overcome that problem ..please help..

Comment: Is useEffect used ? If state update is invoked inside useeffect and same state variable is inside the useEffect array, then it will trigger an infinite loop

Comment: No it will not in infinite loop, state variable changes randomly for showing view conditionally ...will it degrade performance?